# How to download multiple files as a zip using firebase?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

I am working on an Angular project where I have multiple SVG icons and, those are in multiple folders and those folders have multiple files in it that I want to download all as a `.zip` file on a button click.

I want to achieve this by using firebase(as a backend), so anyone has an idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: There is nothing built into Firebase for zipping files. You'll have to do that yourself by writing code for it, either on your client or in server-side code like Cloud Functions.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Are you using Firebase storage? If so, how do multiple folders and files correspond to what you have in stored in storage. Are they zip files to start with or can they be zipped before uploading? Can you clarify what's being asked?

Comment: @Jay what I want is: I have many SVG icons which I show on my angular website...It is just a static website and doesn't have any backend support, I show the icons on my website and all those icons I want to download as a zip file on a button click. is there any way?

Comment: You should post additional clarifying information IN the question so folks get a clear understanding. But the answer is yes, you can do that. Just store all of the icons as separate files in Firebase Storage and then store a previously zipped file in Storage as well that can be downloaded with a button click.